# SQL - Using Subquery with Aggregate Function

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to return the last time entry posted for a particular client, and the case (matter) number associated to that entry. The relationship is one client has many matters, and one matter has many time entries.

I have the code below, but it obviously returns all the matters and not just the one associated to the time entry. I understand why, but tie myself in knots when trying to correct it. Any help much appreciated.

```
select c.CLIENT_CODE,
       c.CLIENT_NAME,
       c.OPEN_DATE,
       mp.EMPLOYEE_NAME,
       MAX(tt.TRAN_DATE)[Last Time],
       m.MATTER_NUMBER
from HBM_CLIENT c
join HBM_MATTER m
 on m.CLIENT_UNO=c.CLIENT_UNO
left join TAT_TIME tt
 on tt.MATTER_UNO=m.MATTER_UNO
left join HBM_PERSNL mp
 on mp.EMPL_UNO=c.RESP_EMPL_UNO
where c.STATUS_CODE = 'Targ'
group by c.CLIENT_CODE,
         c.CLIENT_NAME,
         c.OPEN_DATE,
         mp.EMPLOYEE_NAME,
         m.MATTER_NUMBER
order by OPEN_DATE
```

Comment: why do you wanna group by so many column?

Comment: @Torrezzzz - I suspect the OP has been trying various different approaches but has not quite nailed where the `GROUP BY` should sit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Completely untested but in the right direction

```
select 
  <whatever> 
from 
       HBM_CLIENT c
  join HBM_MATTER m on
    m.CLIENT_UNO = c.CLIENT_UNO
  join TAT_TIME tt on
    tt.MATTER_UNO = m.MATTER_UNO AND
    tt.tran_date = (
       select max(tran_date)
       from TAT_TIME 
       where matter_uno = m.matter_uno)  
where
  m.CLIENT_UNO = ? and 
  c.STATUS_CODE = 'Targ'
```

Comment: Thanks, and almost there, except it is only returning those clients and matters that have time recorded on them, i'd like it to return all target clients, all matters and the last time - whether there is time there or not. Is it a case of tweaking the joins?

Comment: Then you need to change the joins to `left join`.  You will also need to change the 'tt.tran_date =' to `is null or ...`

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is using `row_number()`.  I think the following will do what you want:

```
select c.CLIENT_CODE, c.CLIENT_NAME, c.OPEN_DATE, mp.EMPLOYEE_NAME,
       tt.TRAN_DATE as [Last Time], m.MATTER_NUMBER
from HBM_CLIENT c join
     (select m.*, tt.TRAN_DATE,
             row_number() over (partition by m.CLIENT_UNO
                                order by tt.TRAN_DATE desc
                               ) as seqnum
      from HBM_MATTER m LEFT JOIN
           TAT_TIME tt
           ON tt.MATTER_UNO = m.MATTER_UNO
     ) m
     ON m.CLIENT_UNO = c.CLIENT_UNO and seqnum = 1 left join
     HBM_PERSNL mp
     on mp.EMPL_UNO=c.RESP_EMPL_UNO
where c.STATUS_CODE = 'Targ';
```

I don't think you need the `group by`, unless the other joins create duplicates.